# Is it faster to compress files before copying?

Tags: external-hard-drive, compression, file-transfer

I have around 80 GB of data I need copy to an external hard drive. Would it be faster to compress all the files first and then copy over? Or would the time it takes to compress and decompress take longer that the amount of copying time it will save?

I'm going to be reinstalling windows so basically documents, pictures, videos etc. And one outlook .pst backup file. And there are 28,284 files.

Also any pointers I should be wary of before I begin that could maybe speed up the process?

Comment: Your question is vague because (1) thee are many different compression algorithms, each with its speed/performance characteristics; (2) when is the decompression?  I.E. are you going to write/save the compressed files for long-term archival?  BTW most video and audio files already use a compression scheme, and do not further compress well.

Comment: Not really.  The linked question is about compressing when copying *over a network*, in which case some kinds of compression techniques might actually make sense which are simply impossible for a mass-storage-like connection.

Comment: I recommend timing it yourself if you have the equipment. The problem is there is no correct answer to this; depends on the number of files and sizes of the files. At least with Windows filesystems, tens of thousands of small files summing 80GB will take incredibly long vs few large files.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Why-does-copying-multiple-files-take-longer-time-than-copying-a-single-file-of-same-size

Answer (score 5):

I assume that your external drive is connected via USB, eSATA, Firewire or similar.  In any of these cases, the drive will appear to the host computer as a block device, and the host will ‘talk’ to the hard disk as if it were an internal hard drive.  That’s the whole point of having the ‘USB mass storage’ device class.

This also means that data have to be pushed onto the wire in the precise way they are intended to show up on the hard disk.  There’s no scheme that compresses data on the host, sends the *compressed* data over the USB connection, and is then transparently decompressed just before the now raw, uncompressed data is stored onto the physical media.  So you either have to compress the data beforehand, on the source disk, or jump through contrivances (e.g., putting a NAS in-between and using a compressing network protocol).

Compounding that, unless you have very specific data which are well-compressible, it’s likely that you’ll get very bad compression ratios.  If the bulk of the 80 GB are made of videos, pictures and the like, you might even get negative ratios, as those are already highly compressed using very specialised algorithms.

In any case, getting any significant compression ratio incurs **heavy** amounts of CPU time.  You can get a rough estimate at how badly it will cost you by a simple experiment:  Just try compressing any 1 GB file with 7zip at the highest settings and measure the time.  Then measure how long it takes to *decompress* the result.

Most compression algorithms are optimised for decompression speed, since that’s usually done much more often.  Still, there will be a noticeable or even significant performance penalty, and you will be paying that penalty each time you access the compressed data.

> Or would the time it takes to compress and decompress take longer that the amount of copying time it will save?
>
> Also any pointers I should be wary of before I begin that could maybe speed up the process?

If all you want to accomplish is to get the data from your source drive to your external drive, then the copy is most likely already finished by the time you get the answer here. :o)  Especially since 80 GB are not that big a deal anymore; assuming a ballpark number of 10 MB/s you’ll wait less than three hours.  Compressing 80 GB will take *much* longer.

---

Something that *does* merit considering though is **interrupted transfers**.  Having to restart that 80 GB-transfer at the 95% mark and having to restart from scratch is… annoying, to say the least.  The canonical tool in this case is `rsync`, which can save you tremendous time, much more than compression might give you.  The price is a small investment in how to use it, but you will not have a performance penalty on reading the data afterwards, which is a big plus.

TL;DR:  From what I gather from your question, `rsync` (or similar) is the way to go.  Except for very specific circumstances, compression will be a big waste of time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. It really depends on what you are compressing and what is the method of compression. 80GB of data might be worth compressing IF it was to remain in that compressed state. If you are looking to have quick access to that data then no, compression would only hinder that capability. Really compression is not so much software as it is hardware since it depends on the performance of server or computer you are compressing on.

Really in the end you would save yourself the time by just copying the data raw and not compressed that's not really what compression was designed for.

Answer (score 1):

This depends totally on the type of data you are backing up and the device you are backing up too.    I have a large quantity of highly compressible data which I back up to a USB 2 drive on a regular basis.  Compressing the data greatly speeds up the transfer because USB 2 is substantially slower then the the time it takes to compress the data, and the saving is large.

Conversely, if you have a fast USB3 drive or compressed data you will get less of an advantage.

The type of compression you use also needs to be factored in, as well as your CPU.  Zip and similar are relatively lightweight, so compressing is fast, however some compression algorythms are much more CPU intensive.

I'm a linux person, so I haven't used it, but you may be able to get the best of both worlds (ie easily accessible documents, faster write times) by using [NTFS compression](http://www.howtogeek.com/133264/how-to-use-ntfs-compression-and-when-you-might-want-to/) on your filesystem.

Answer (score -2):

Answer for you: no.
It is only faster if you only leave one commpressed file in compressed format on external file. But if you decompress file on the same hard, it will be slow.
By the way, what files do you have, and how much files do you have?

Comment: I'm going to be reinstalling windows so basically documents, pictures, videos etc. And one outlook .pst backup file. And there is 28,284 files.

Comment: Documents, pictures and videos?  Don’t even bother, complete waste of time.  Just start the transfer and watch a movie and hope the transfer goes through.  I’d still use `rsync`, but if it’s a one-shot operation then it maybe isn’t worth the hassle.